# firefox in fullscreen mode on raspberry pi 4 (debian bookworm)

Tags: linux, bash, firefox, debian

I need my raspberry (new Pi OS with debian bookworm) to show a certain web page in full mode, so I run this script

```bash
firefox -kiosk -private 'www.example.com'
```

and can expect firefox to open [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) in full screen according to documentation. This does not happen in my case. The window might be "full screen" but is not centered. I have a workaround for that at the moment, my script looks like this

```bash
firefox 'www.example.com'
sleep 15
xdotool key F11
```

Do you have ideas why the -kiosk flag does not work?

Comment: when in doubt - [read the docs](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox/CommandLineOptions#--kiosk_URL) ... it's `-private --kiosk URL` you'll need - note the order (since --kiosk requires the URL value) and the number of `-`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem for chromium instead of firefox, the solution might also work:

`firefox -private --start-maximized --start-fullscreen 'www.example.com'`

I found the answer here: https://github.com/raspberrypi/bookworm-feedback/issues/31